# AFL not taking input from Stdin

Tags: testing, fuzzy, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I am trying to Fuzz a binary file that takes input from the user(Stdin). When I try Afl-fuzz and then my binary something like

```
afl-fuzz a.out
```

It asks for the required parameters that are specifying the input and output directories.

```
afl-fuzz -i input_dir -o output_dir a.out
```

It gives the error *Looks like there are no valid test cases in the input directory*.
If I provide a sample test case and try again it starts fuzzing but doesn't ask for input from the user.
I am a total noob in this field so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What means "but doesn't ask for input from the user"?  AFL is mutating your sample and use it as stdin for your program a.out.

Comment: try adding "@@" at the end, after a.out...